# Outlier Detection on common variable name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation, outliers

I've would like to create a column to detect outliers in a large dataset. A sample of the dataset is

| Item | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Book A | 5.0 |
| Book A | 3.5 |
| Book A | 12.0 |
| Book B | 6.0 |
| Book B | 8.0 |
| Book C | 3.0 |
| Book B | 6.0 |
| Book C | 3.5 |
| Book A | 3.8 |
| Book B | 13.0 |
| Book A | 5.1 |
| Book B | 7.0 |
| Book A | 11.5 |
| Book C | 3.8 |
| Book A | 5.5 |
| Book A | 6.5 |
| Book B | 13.5 |
| Book A | 5.5 |
| Book C | 3.5 |
| Book A | 1.2 |

```
df = structure(list(Item = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Book A", 
"Book B", "Book C"), class = "factor"), Cost = c(5, 3.5, 12, 
6, 8, 3, 6, 3.5, 3.8, 13, 5.1, 7, 11.5, 3.8, 5.5, 6.5, 13.5, 
5.5, 3.5, 1.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L
))
```

I would like to detect the outlier (for e.g. if the cost is 60% higher or lower than majority average of the particular item) and output a column as follows

| Item | Cost | Outlier (Y/N) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book A | 5.0 | N |
| Book A | 3.5 | N |
| Book A | 12.0 | Y |
| Book B | 6.0 | N |
| Book B | 8.0 | N |
| Book C | 3.0 | N |
| Book B | 6.0 | N |
| Book C | 3.5 | N |
| Book A | 3.8 | N |
| Book B | 13.0 | Y |
| Book A | 5.1 | N |
| Book B | 7.0 | N |
| Book A | 11.5 | Y |
| Book C | 3.8 | N |
| Book A | 5.5 | N |
| Book A | 6.5 | N |
| Book B | 13.5 | Y |
| Book A | 5.5 | N |
| Book C | 3.5 | N |
| Book A | 1.2 | Y |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise(outlier = mean(Cost), 
            offset = outlier * 0.6, 
            higher_value = outlier + offset, 
            lower_value = outlier - offset) %>%
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  transmute(Item, Cost, 
            Outlier = ifelse(Cost < lower_value | Cost > higher_value, 'Y', 'N'))

#     Item Cost Outlier
#1  Book A  5.0       N
#2  Book A  3.5       N
#3  Book A 12.0       Y
#4  Book B  6.0       N
#5  Book B  8.0       N
#6  Book C  3.0       N
#7  Book B  6.0       N
#8  Book C  3.5       N
#9  Book A  3.8       N
#10 Book B 13.0       Y
#11 Book A  5.1       N
#12 Book B  7.0       N
#13 Book A 11.5       Y
#14 Book C  3.8       N
#15 Book A  5.5       N
#16 Book B  6.5       N
#17 Book B 13.5       Y
#18 Book A  5.5       N
#19 Book C  3.5       N
#20 Book A  1.2       Y
```

If you want to find the outlier for each `Item` separately.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  summarise(outlier = mean(Cost), 
            offset = outlier * 0.6, 
            higher_value = outlier + offset, 
            lower_value = outlier - offset) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'Item') %>%
  transmute(Item, Cost, 
            Outlier = ifelse(Cost < lower_value | Cost > higher_value, 'Y', 'N'))
```

Comment: Thanks! You're taking the average of all the items? I was actually referring to the majority average of the particular item

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Majority Average". If you want to calculate average of every `Item` separately please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! That actually answers my question, appreciate it!

Comment: @RonakShah How were you able to get `between` to work?  I can't get your code to work without using `rowwise` call

Comment: I just realised that I was using `between` from `data.table` and that is why it was working. I changed it to use with `>` and `<`. @JahiZamy